# How to inspect "multi-object" return type

Tags: java, arrays, generics, reflection, collections

Is there a common reflection approach to find out whether java method returns a set of objects like array, list, set, collection and other iterable subinterfaces?
The story behind is that I need to inspect third-party method's return type and say two things:

- Does method return set of objects (in
  human sense)?
- If yes - what is the component type?

For example if method's return type is `Vector<A>`, `A[]`, `Set<A>`, etc, I want that `A` to be returned by my code.
I'm new to reflection/generics, don't want to re-invent the wheel and not sure my approach is correct. Here's what I've done so far:

```
  private boolean isMultiple(Class clazz) {
    return clazz.isArray() || Iterable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
  }

  private Class getReturnComponentType(Method m) {
    Class clazz = m.getReturnType();
    if(!isMultiple(clazz)) return clazz; // Not a collection
    // Collection
    if(clazz.isArray()) {
      // How do I get Array's component type?
      // return null;
    } else {
      // How do I get Iterable component type?
      // return null;
    }
  }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To get Iterable component type: Besides `getReturnType()` also use [`getGenericReturnType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericReturnType%28%29) to get generic types. Then compare it to [`Type`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) subinterfaces: GenericArrayType, ParameterizedType.
2. To get Array component type use [`clazz.getComponentType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType%28%29).

Comment: I'd say that then use Collection.class.isAssignableFrom() or Iterable.class.isAssignableFrom() or Class.isArray().

Comment: He already does this. Now he needs the type parameter (i.e. T in List<T>)

Comment: thanks. I worried mostly about my isMultiple method, glad it's ok.